# Haskell get Matrix from bmp Image

Tags: haskell, image-processing

Hi Everyone Im beginner in Haskell I want to read and extract matrix of pixels (numbers) from a grayscale bmp image in haskell
anyone has idea how to do that I searched online without finding any clues thank you

Comment: Seriously? There are lots and lots of question about loading images in Haskell. If this question is mostly about how to get the image in some specific matrix format, then you should **a)** clarify _which matrix format_ and **b)** generally expand on what you've tried, demonstrate what didn't work good enough when you just followed the instructions on another question, etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are not as many tutorials on this topic as there should be, but it is at least not as hard as it might seem at first. As @leftaroundabout pointed out, the first thing you need is to decide on the library you want to use for dealing matrices. I personally would recommend [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv) for array manipulation and [`massiv-io`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv-io) for reading and writing images. You didn't specify what exactly you want to do with the image, so all I am gonna provide in this example is reading a bmp image into an array, printing some stuff about the matrix and the writing it in jpg format:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Massiv.Array as A
import Data.Massiv.Array.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  img <- readImage "frog.bmp" :: IO (Image S SRGB Word8)
  putStrLn $ "Size: " ++ show (size img)
  putStrLn $ "Pixel at <row:10, col:20>: " ++ show (img ! (10 :. 20))
  writeImageAuto "frog.jpg" img
```

[image: frog bmp]

Then if you save that snippet into a file named `convert-bmp.hs`, place `frog.bmp` image next to it then using [`stack`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#installupgrade):

```sh
$ stack --resolver lts-16.25 runghc --package massiv --package massiv-io convert-bmp.hs 
Size: Sz (200 :. 320)
Pixel at <row:10, col:20>: <SRGB:( 61, 64, 35)>
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, sorry about the lack of information, I have digit bmp pictures in grayscale and I m trying to turn the matrix I get from the bitmap after I read it to a vector in order to train my neural network   I tried  this using Repa  but it is to working `  
         x <- readImageFromBMP "../dat/img0.bmp"
         return toUnboxed  x`. but it is not working